# Amazon Alexa custom slot memo

Tags: javascript, alexa-skills-kit

I am creating an Alexa skill that needs to retrieve various things such as *Date, File number, etc*. I also need it to get the *"Description"* that a user says to it and be able to retain it.

For example:

> "Alexa, description, patent drafting"

so I would need Alexa to be able to retain the `"Patent drafting"`. I am not to sure how I should go about this and any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **slots** to get this piece of information for your skill. 
You'll need slots like `Date` (use built-in `AMAZON.Date` as it's slot type), `FileNumber` (use `AMAZON.Number`), and `Description` (this would be a custom slot, where you need to provide slot values explicitly).

Now you make all of the slots required in the build section of your Alexa skill builder. And you also need to provide **prompts** (i.e. what Alexa will say to ask for the value of this slot) and **utterances** (i.e. what user will speak in response to those prompts). The utterances should have the slot variable. For example: *"Note the date to {Date}"*

Once this is done, you'll need to have a look on [`Dialog.Delegate`](http://**prompts**%20i.e.%20what%20Alexa%20will%20say%20to%20ask%20for%20this%20slot%20and%20**utterances**%20that%20is%20what%20user%20will%20speak%20in%20response%20to%20those%20prompts) Directive. Your skill must return this Dialog, in order to retrieve the input data.

This should not be a problem. But if you face any, comment below and I'll tell  the step-by-step procedure and even the code to get this done.

Comment: Could you make a youtube tutorial? I don't understand how to create dialog... And this phrase 'To use these prompts and utterances in your skill, return the Dialog.Delegate directive in your skill's response.' how???

Comment: I can make a tutorial, but it would certainly take some time. Give me a day or two. Otherwise you can just mail me or something.

Comment: Nikhil Wagh, thank you. my email dm.grinko@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

So for the description.. I can only get the values that I predefined within the **utterances**? I would not be able to program Alexa to have it retrieve whatever I say? Because there could be a large variety of things that could be said.

Comment: Put this in the comment, not in the answer.

And this is not true. You'll be able to retrieve any thing that would somehow match with your utterance.

For eg : Suppose you have this as your utterance : "The description is {Description}". And the user says "The description is XYZ". Even if you didn't had *XYZ* in your slot values, it would still be matched. And your slot `Description` would still be able to hold the value *XYZ*.

Comment: I'm saying for the description slot, there could be an infinite number of different descriptions that could be said. Is there no way to get a user to say a description without having it predefined in the slot values?

Comment: Is this where the Dialog.Delegate comes into play? Sorry I'm just a student programmer with 6 months experience so my knowledge is not at the level that I would like yet.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get this : `Is there no way to get a user to say a description without having it predefined in the slot values? `. It is not necessary to have all of your *descriptions* in your slot values defined before hand. See I had a skill which had `City`, as a slot. I can't have all of the city name defined already, right. I just gave some city names to my skill, and it worked for any city name. Did this answer your question?

Comment: City is already a predefined slot though. If I use a custom slot (which I would have to for description) it forces me to add a slot value/values. What would I fill in those values as?

Comment: Add some values for `Description` slot, and test for a new value of description (which is not added in the list of values of `Description` slot). Tell me if it works or not.